# Print all items in all dictionary lists

Tags: python, dictionary, sequence

```
## Dictionary List
G046 = {'046-HOST1':'192.168.1.10', '046-HOST2':'10.1.0.1'}
G688 = {'688-HOST1':'8.8.8.8', '688-HOST2' : '123.3.3.3'}   
## Group List 
GroupList = ['G046', 'G688']
for groupname in GroupList:
    print ('Groupname is', groupname)  ## prints "G046" and "G688"
    print (dict(groupname).keys())     ## <---- error occurs
```

I want to print all of the items in all dictionary lists. But I got the following message:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to turn a string into a dict. That's just what [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) does, but that doesn't make sense here.

Instead, just put the objects directly into `GroupList`.

```
GroupList = [G046, G688]
for group in GroupList:
    print (group.keys())
```

> But I really want is items in each Dictionary can be printed in separated lines.

I'd just use [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) for this and be done with it:

```
from pprint import pprint
GroupList = [G046, G688]
for group in GroupList:
    pprint(group, width=1) # pass a small width to force multiline output
```

Comment: But I really want is items in each Dictionary can be printed in separated lines. EX: Line 1: '046-HOST1':'192.168.1.10' Line 2: '046-HOST2':'10.1.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
G046 = {'046-HOST1':'192.168.1.10', '046-HOST2':'10.1.0.1'}
G688 = {'688-HOST1':'8.8.8.8', '688-HOST2' : '123.3.3.3'}   

GroupList = [G046, G688] # Make the items the dictionaries themselves

for groupname in GroupList:
    print ('Groupname is', groupname)
    print (groupname.keys())
```

Output:

```
('Groupname is', {'046-HOST2': '10.1.0.1', '046-HOST1': '192.168.1.10'})
['046-HOST2', '046-HOST1']
('Groupname is', {'688-HOST2': '123.3.3.3', '688-HOST1': '8.8.8.8'})
['688-HOST2', '688-HOST1']
```

Basically, all I did was make the items in `GroupList` be the dictionaries, not strings.  I also removed `dict` in `print (dict(groupname).keys())` because it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

As ICodez and Matt Ball pointed out, the better way to do it is just use a list of dictionaries, not names. You could even make a list of names to print, if you really want to print names for the dictionaries too.

But if you really want to do it your way, you want to use `locals()`, which is a special function that returns the dictionary mapping the names of all local variables to their values.

```
GroupList = ['G046', 'G688']
for groupname in GroupList:
    print 'Groupname is', groupname
    print locals()[groupname].keys()
```

The first part of the last line, `locals()[groupname]` uses the name of your dictionary variable to get the actual dictionary, and then the `.keys()` gets the keys, as you wanted.